# NFA to DFA Conversion Help

Tags: automata

Consider the language of all words over {a, b} that either begins and ends with aa or bb (but both are
the same within each word). That is, {ccycc | c ∈ {a, b}, y ∈ Σ
∗}

[image]

I have drawn the resulting NFA for the language described above, what would the corresponding DFA look like? What would the steps look like to get from an NFA to a DFA?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are very close to a DFA already.  First add a 'dead state' (non-final) with additional transitions to it from q1, q2, q5, and q6 on symbols b, a, b, and a, respectively, plus an arrow from the state to itself on a and b.  Second, split q7 into two final states q8, q9, with q5->q8 on a and q6->q9 on b, and add loops q8->q8 on a, q9->q9 on b, and cross-transitions q8->q6 on b, q9->q5 on a.

Comment: That doesn’t quite work: you end up accepting $aaaabb$, which is not in the language.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Would the DFA I recently posted work?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I believe this DFA would work.

Comment: Almost, but you need the $b$ transition from $q_8$ to go to $q_4$, and the $a$ transition from $q_7$ to go to $q_3$. As it stands, it accepts $aabaaba$, which it should not do.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! @BrianM.Scott